# How to check if link is valid / skip if not for background image

Tags: jquery, http-status-code-404, preloading

I have an array of image links, some of which are not valid.  I am trying to loop through and set the background image to these photos.  However, when I try to set one to the invalid links (which return a 404 page) my code breaks.  Can anyone suggest a way to check to see if the link is valid or (even better) skip over an invalid link?

Here is how I retrieve the links (from a JSON feed)

```
url = feed[index]['images']['url'];
imageArray.push[index]
```

And here is where I set the image src value

```
imageArray = ['link1', 'link2']
for(var y = 0; y < 1; y++){
    document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('"+imageArray[y]+"')";
} //Here is where my code breaks
```

I just do not see where to put the `try/catch` statement. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function loadImage(){
    var xhr;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.status == 404){
            // 404 Error!
        }
        else if(xhr.readyState == 5 && xhr.status == 200){
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", "http://test.com/" + id + ".png", true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Please do modify the image setting line... Rest it will work like a charm

Comment: I am really interested in using this to load images to my cache, these urls have already been request through $.ajax.  I do not understand where to implement this function

Comment: it will automatically use cache if image is cached by browser.